# fcitx fails to start to use

Tags: ubuntu, input, fcitx

I have installed fcitx to input Chinese method in my ubuntu 16.04 but it fails to start.

```
panda:~$ (WARN-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx-config/fcitx-config.c:172) missing value: Name
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-x11.conf
(WARN-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx-config/fcitx-config.c:172) missing value: Name
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-clipboard.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-sunpinyin.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-unicode.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-fullwidth-char.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-table.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-remote-module.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-chttrans.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-vk.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xim.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-pinyin.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-quickphrase.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-imselector.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkbdbus.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-keyboard.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-xkb.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-classic-ui.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-autoeng.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-cloudpinyin.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-pinyin-enhance.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-notificationitem.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-spell.conf
(INFO-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:151) Load Addon Config File:fcitx-punc.conf
(WARN-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:298) Disable addon fcitx-xkbdbus, dependency fcitx-xkb,fcitx-dbus cannot be satisfied.
(WARN-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/addon.c:298) Disable addon fcitx-notificationitem, dependency fcitx-dbus cannot be satisfied.
(ERROR-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/frontend/xim/xim.c:240) Start XIM error. Another XIM daemon named fcitx is running?
(ERROR-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/instance.c:440) Exiting.
(ERROR-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/lib/fcitx/frontend.c:565) No available frontend
```

I also perform fcitx-diagnose and get,

```
# System Info:
```

1.  `uname -a`:

```
    Linux panda 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

2. `lsb_release -a`:

   ```
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
   Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
   Release:    16.04
   Codename:   xenial
   ```
3. `lsb_release -d`:

   ```
   Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
   ```
4. `/etc/lsb-release`:

   ```
   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
   DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
   DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
   ```
5. `/etc/os-release`:

   ```
   NAME="Ubuntu"
   VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
   ID=ubuntu
   ID_LIKE=debian
   PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
   VERSION_ID="16.04"
   HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
   SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
   BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
   VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
   UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
   ```
6. Desktop Environment:

   Desktop environment is `gnome3`.
7. Bash Version:

   ```
   BASH_VERSION='4.3.46(1)-release'
   ```

## Environment:

1. DISPLAY:

   ```
   DISPLAY=':0'
   ```
2. Keyboard Layout:

   1. `setxkbmap`:

      ```
      xkb_keymap {
          xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
          xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
          xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
          xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
          xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
      };
      ```
   2. `xprop`:

      ```
      _XKB_RULES_NAMES(STRING) = "evdev", "pc105", "us", "", ""
      ```
3. Locale:

   1. All locale:

      ```
      C
      C.UTF-8
      en_AG
      en_AG.utf8
      en_AU.utf8
      en_BW.utf8
      en_CA.utf8
      en_DK.utf8
      en_GB.utf8
      en_HK.utf8
      en_IE.utf8
      en_IN
      en_IN.utf8
      en_NG
      en_NG.utf8
      en_NZ.utf8
      en_PH.utf8
      en_SG.utf8
      en_US.utf8
      en_ZA.utf8
      en_ZM
      en_ZM.utf8
      en_ZW.utf8
      POSIX
      zh_CN.utf8
      zh_SG.utf8
      ```
   2. Current locale:

      ```
      LANG=en_US.UTF-8
      LANGUAGE=en_US
      LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
      LC_ALL=
      ```
4. Directories:

   1. Home:

      ```
      /home/huangming
      ```
   2. `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}`:

      Environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set.

      Current value of `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is `~/.config` (`/home/huangming/.config`).
   3. Fcitx Settings Directory:

      Current fcitx settings directory is `~/.config/fcitx` (`/home/huangming/.config/fcitx`).
5. Current user:

   The script is run as huangming (1000).

## Fcitx State:

1. executable:

   Found fcitx at `/usr/bin/fcitx`.
2. version:

   Fcitx version: `4.2.9.1`
3. process:

   Found 1 fcitx process:

   ```
   22793 fcitx
   ```
4. `fcitx-remote`:

   **Cannot connect to fcitx correctly.**

## Fcitx Configure UI:

1. Config Tool Wrapper:

   Found fcitx-configtool at `/usr/bin/fcitx-configtool`.
2. Config GUI for gtk2:

   **Config GUI for gtk2 not found.**
3. Config GUI for gtk3:

   Found `fcitx-config-gtk3` at `/usr/bin/fcitx-config-gtk3`.
4. Config GUI for kde:

   **`kcmshell4` not found.**

## Frontends setup:

### Xim:

1. `${XMODIFIERS}`:

   Environment variable XMODIFIERS is set to "@im=fcitx" correctly.
   Xim Server Name from Environment variable is fcitx.
2. XIM_SERVERS on root window:

   Xim server name is the same with that set in the environment variable.

### Qt:

1. qt4 - `${QT4_IM_MODULE}`:

   Environment variable QT_IM_MODULE is set to "fcitx" correctly.
2. qt5 - `${QT_IM_MODULE}`:

   Environment variable QT_IM_MODULE is set to "fcitx" correctly.
3. Qt IM module files:
   **Cannot find fcitx input method module for Qt4.**
   **Cannot find fcitx input method module for Qt5.**

### Gtk:

1. gtk - `${GTK_IM_MODULE}`:

   Environment variable GTK_IM_MODULE is set to "fcitx" correctly.
2. `gtk-query-immodules`:

   1. gtk 2:

      **Cannot find `gtk-query-immodules` for gtk 2**

      **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 2.**
   2. gtk 3:

      **Cannot find `gtk-query-immodules` for gtk 3**

      **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 3.**
3. Gtk IM module cache:

   1. gtk 2:

      Found immodules cache for gtk `2.24.30` at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache`.
      Version Line:

      ```
      # Created by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk2.0-0/gtk-query-immodules-2.0 from gtk+-2.24.30
      ```

      **Failed to find fcitx in immodule cache at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache`**

      **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 2 in cache.**
   2. gtk 3:

      Found immodules cache for gtk `3.18.9` at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache`.
      Version Line:

      ```
      # Created by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 from gtk+-3.18.9
      ```

      **Failed to find fcitx in immodule cache at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache`**

      **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 3 in cache.**
4. Gtk IM module files:

   1. gtk 2:

      All found Gtk 2 immodule files exist.
   2. gtk 3:

      All found Gtk 3 immodule files exist.

## Configuration:

### Fcitx Addons:

1. Addon Config Dir:

   Found fcitx addon config directory: `/usr/share/fcitx/addon`.
2. Addon List:

   1. Found 22 enabled addons:

      ```
      fcitx-autoeng
      fcitx-chttrans
      fcitx-classic-ui
      fcitx-cloudpinyin
      fcitx-fullwidth-char
      fcitx-imselector
      fcitx-keyboard
      fcitx-notificationitem
      fcitx-pinyin
      fcitx-pinyin-enhance
      fcitx-punc
      fcitx-quickphrase
      fcitx-remote
      fcitx-spell
      fcitx-sunpinyin
      fcitx-table
      fcitx-unicode
      fcitx-vk
      fcitx-x11
      fcitx-xim
      fcitx-xkb
      fcitx-xkbdbus
      ```
   2. Found 1 disabled addons:

      ```
      fcitx-clipboard
      ```
3. Addon Libraries:

   All libraries for all addons are found.
4. User Interface:

   Found 1 enabled user interface addons:

   ```
   fcitx-classic-ui
   ```

### Input Methods:

1. Found 1 enabled input methods:

   ```
   fcitx-keyboard-us
   ```
2. Default input methods:

   You only have one keyboard input method enabled. You may want to add another input method to input other languages.

## Log:

1. `date`:

   ```
   Sun Apr  9 16:16:42 EDT 2017
   ```
2. `~/.config/fcitx/log/`:

   ```
   total 4
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 huangming huangming 44 Mar 23 16:54 crash.log
   ```
3. `~/.config/fcitx/log/crash.log`:

   ```
   fcitx: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
   ```

Any comments for help?

Answer (score 1):

```
(ERROR-25191 /build/fcitx-PSoVA1/fcitx-4.2.9.1/src/frontend/xim/xim.c:240) Start XIM error. Another XIM daemon named fcitx is running?
```

indicates that `fcitx` has started

Under Input Methods from `fcitx-diagnose`, you have only one method enabled `fcitx-keyboard-us`. You need to add at least one, for example, `googlepinyin`